# collection_select set option value of :include_blank to zero

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails app, i have a drop down box where i retrieve all groups from the Group table and display them using the collection_select tag.

When the user selects 'None', I want to pass '0' as option value.

Currently, an empty string is passed.

Is there a way to include option value = 0 for 'None'?

```
<%= f.collection_select :SUB_GROUP, Group.all, :Group_ID, :Group_ID, :include_blank => 'None' %>
```

Many many thanks for any suggestion provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `options_for_select` in combination with `select_tag` you can achieve that using this:

```
options_for_select(
   [['None', '0']].concat(
      Group.all.collect { |g| [g.group_id.to_s, g.group_id.to_s] }
   )
)
```

In order to keep your views uncluttered, you might want to generalize and move this into a helper method with a reasonable name.

Comment: You're welcome. :) By the way, in RoR the convention is to use lowercase names separated by an underline for table columns and active_record attributes.